# how to bind ul List in mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on application in asp.net mvc 4. Here I have a Model named Property as

```
public class Property
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public long Property_ID { get; set; }
    public string Images { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; } 
    public long PID { get; set; }
    public long Property_Type { get; set; }
    public long PropertyDetail_Type { get; set; }
    public long Country { get; set; }
    public long State { get; set; }
    public long City { get; set; }
    public string Bedroom { get; set; }
    public string Bathroom { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public string Purpose { get; set; }
    public long User_ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public string StateName { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public long Emp_ID { get; set; }
    public int seqnum { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public SelectList PropertyList { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Property> PLIST { get; set; }
}

public class PropertyContext
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SQLCONN"].ToString());

    public IEnumerable<Property> GetPropertyList(long CityID, string Location, int Property, int Purpose, int Bedroom, int Bathroom, decimal Price1, decimal Price2)
    {            
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmdProperty = new SqlCommand("SP_CheckProperty", con);
        cmdProperty.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", CityID);
        cmdProperty.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", Location);
        cmdProperty.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Property", Property);
        cmdProperty.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Purpose", Purpose);
        cmdProperty.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bedroom", Bedroom);
        cmdProperty.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bathroom", Bathroom);
        cmdProperty.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price1", Price1);
        cmdProperty.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price2", Price2);
        cmdProperty.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlDataAdapter daProperty = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdProperty);
        DataTable dtProperty = new DataTable();
        daProperty.Fill(dtProperty);

        Search obj = new Search();
        con.Close();
        return dtProperty.AsEnumerable().Select(row =>
        {
            return new Property
            {
                ID = Convert.ToInt64(row["ID"]),
                Property_ID = Convert.ToInt64(row["Property_ID"]),
                Images = Convert.ToString(row["Images"]),
                Title = Convert.ToString(row["Title"]),
                PID = Convert.ToInt64(row["PID"]),
                Property_Type = Convert.ToInt64(row["Property_Type"]),
                PropertyDetail_Type = Convert.ToInt64(row["PropertyDetail_Type"]),
                Country = Convert.ToInt64(row["Country"]),
                State = Convert.ToInt64(row["State"]),
                City = Convert.ToInt64(row["City"]),
                Bedroom = Convert.ToString(row["Bedroom"]),
                Bathroom = Convert.ToString(row["Bathroom"]),
                Location = Convert.ToString(row["Location"]),
                Price = Convert.ToDecimal(row["Price"]),
                Description = Convert.ToString(row["Description"]),
                Area = Convert.ToString(row["Area"]),
                Status = Convert.ToInt32(row["Status"]),
                User_ID = Convert.ToInt64(row["User_ID"]),
                Date = Convert.ToDateTime(row["Date"]),
                CityName = Convert.ToString(row["CityName"]),
                StateName = Convert.ToString(row["StateName"]),
                CountryName = Convert.ToString(row["CountryName"]),
                Emp_ID = Convert.ToInt64(row["Emp_ID"]),
                seqnum = Convert.ToInt32(row["seqnum"])
            };

        });

    }
}
```

In the above class there is a method named GetPropertyList which is taking some argument and returning list of Properties after fetching from Sql database. I have a controller named Home which have a action named DisplayDetails which is called after form submission. This action takes parameter of Model of search type. This model named search have same members which is used as argument in GetPropertyList  method. My action is :

```
public ActionResult DisplayDetails(Search objCust)
    {

        if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["Bathroom"].ToString())) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["Bathroom"].ToString())) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["City"].ToString())) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["PropertyType"].ToString())) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["Purpose"].ToString())))
        {

            objCust.Bathroom = Convert.ToInt32((Request.Form["Bathroom"].ToString()));
            objCust.Bedroom = Convert.ToInt32((Request.Form["Bedroom"].ToString()));
            objCust.PropertyType = Convert.ToInt32((Request.Form["PropertyType"].ToString()));
            objCust.Purpose = Convert.ToInt32((Request.Form["Purpose"].ToString()));
            objCust.Maximum = Convert.ToDecimal(Request.Form["Maximum"].ToString());
            objCust.Minimum = Convert.ToDecimal((Request.Form["Minimum"].ToString()));
            objCust.Location = Convert.ToString((Request.Form["Location"].ToString()));
            objCust.City = Convert.ToInt64(Request.Form["City"].ToString());

            if (objCust.Minimum.ToString().Equals("1"))
                objCust.Minimum = 1;
            else
                objCust.Minimum = Convert.ToDecimal(objCust.Min);
            if ((objCust.Maximum.ToString().Equals("1")))
                objCust.Maximum = 1;
            else if ((objCust.Maximum.Equals("17")))
                objCust.Maximum = 1;
            else
                objCust.Maximum = Convert.ToDecimal(objCust.Max);

            PropertyContext MCon = new PropertyContext();
            Property objProperty = new Property();

            objProperty.PropertyList = new SelectList(MCon.GetPropertyList(objCust.City, objCust.Location, objCust.PropertyType, objCust.Purpose, objCust.Bedroom, objCust.Bathroom, objCust.Minimum, objCust.Maximum));

AutoComplete1.Models.IEnumerable<Property>{ objProperty.PropertyList});

            return View("DisplayDetails", new List<Property> { objProperty });                
        }
        else
        {
            Search objCity = new Search();
            objCity.Property = new SelectList(MCon.GetPropertyList(), "ID", "PropertyName");
            objCity.PurposeList = new SelectList(MCon.GetPurpose(), "ID", "PurposeName");
            return View("Default", objCity);
        }
}
```

My Display Details View is :

```
 @model IEnumerable<AutoComplete1.Models.Property>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DisplayDetails";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }

<h2>DisplayDetails</h2>
<ul class="row">

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    var @impath = item.Images;

    <li class="col-sm-4"> 
          <!--======= TAGS =========--> 
          <span class="tag font-montserrat rent"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Purpose)</span>
          <section> 
        <!--======= IMAGE =========-->
        <div class="img"> <img class="img-responsive" src="@impath" alt="" />
          <!--======= IMAGE HOVER =========-->
          <div class="over-proper"> <a href="#." class="btn font-montserrat">more details</a> </div>
        @*</div>*@
        <!--======= HOME INNER DETAILS =========-->
        <ul class="home-in">
          <li><span><i class="fa fa-home"></i> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Area)</span></li>
          <li><span><i class="fa fa-bed"></i> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Bedroom)</span></li>
          <li><span><i class="fa fa-tty"></i> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Bathroom)</span></li>
        </ul>
        <!--======= HOME DETAILS =========-->
        <div class="detail-sec"> <a href="#." class="font-montserrat">sweet home for small family</a> <span class="locate"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Location), @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CityName)</span>
          <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description) </p>
          <div class="share-p"> <span class="price font-montserrat">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)</span> <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i> <i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i> </div>
        </div>
      </section>
</li>

}

</ul>
```

Everything is working fine here. Conroller action DisplayDetails is getting correct parameter on form submission. Correct Prroperty List is coming from the datbase. but when i am sending the list to the view it is not binding to the correct value. Can any one get me help here.

Comment: All your `DisplayDetails` method does is return a new `List<Property>` which is populated with one new `Property` object (all its properties except `PropertyList` will be the default values)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke  then what i have to for its solution. Actually i have tried a lot to solve it but unable to find the solution.